# Como passar várias variáveis para uma View no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Como passo várias variáveis para uma mesma view? Algo como:

```
return "view('textos.index', ['textos1' => $textos1, 'textos2' => $textos2, 'textos3' => $textos3]);"
```

Comment: O correto não seria `return view('textos.index', ['textos1' => $textos1, 'textos2' => $textos2, 'textos3' => $textos3]);`?

Answer (score 3):

É exatamente assim:

```
return view('textos.index', [
                 'texto1' => $texto1,
                 'texto2' => $texto2, 
                 'texto3' => $texto3
             ]);
```

*E na view você acessa dessa forma:*

```
<div>
    <p>{{$texto1}}</p>
    <p>{{$texto2}}</p>
    <p>{{$texto3}}</p>
</div>
```

A única coisa errada aí é que você colocou entre aspas, então voce estava retornando uma `String`

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso, você também pode utilizar a função `compact`.

Essa função captura os nomes das variáveis locais e cria um array associativo com os devidos valores.

Então, poderia ser feito assim:

```
$texto1 = 1;
$texto2 = 2;
$text3 = 3;

return view('home', compact('texto1', 'texto2', 'texto3'));
```